# Accessing iPhones Camera to Record Video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, video-streaming, streaming

I've been trying to find any and all information on this for a while now, and I can't find anything anywhere. Let me give you some code, so you have a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

I have an App Component that just displays a title in the navigation element and is supposed to display a button that says "Record" if PassiveActive is false and a live video if PassiveActive is true.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import PassiveActive from './Components/PassiveActive';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </nav>
            <main>
                <PassiveActive />
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The React Component below is just supposed to determine what is displayed on the screen, the option to record or the video being recorded.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function PassiveActive() {
    const [PassiveActive, setPassiveActive] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setPassiveActive(!PassiveActive);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <main>
                {
                    PassiveActive === false 
                    ? 
                    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Record</button> 
                    : 
                    <>
                        <span onClick={handleSubmit}>X</span>
                        <p>Video</p>
                    </>
                }
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default PassiveActive;
```

When I press the "Record" button, I want to begin recording the video on my phone. Like, I want the app to access my camera and use it to record a video.

I'll continue to look for new ways to solve this problem, but until then, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a web app?  If so, would you want any random app on the web (which, as far as your phone is concerned, this would be) to be able to access your camera?

Comment: No, of course not. But, I definitely grant permission to some apps to access my camera to improve my experience with the app.